# A question around the access token frontend get after authentication

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, frontend, access-token

When thinking the OAuth2.x grant types (e.g. code or password or implicit grant type), eventually, the javascript web frontend application will get an JWT **access token** as a response for the authentication request (e.g. login user) .

Then, the frontend will use above **access token** (during its valid period) also in bearer header of subsequent requests that are sent to backend, which means this **access token** will need to be stored in frontend side so that when forming the subsequent requests, it use the **access token** in request header. Am I making sense here?

My two questions:

**Q1.** isn't it unsafe to store the **access token** in javascript frontend? Because developer tools of the browser can unveil this **access token** which could be used by malicious users. Am I making sense here?  If so, what is the proper way to host this *access token* in frontend once it gets it after authentication?

**Q2.** If frontend also wants to validate the token by checking the claims inside, it would mean the public key is needed in frontend, is that a fine way to go? If not, what would be the better way if frontend needs to validate the stored token when forming the subsequent requests to backend?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The concern in your first question is actually valid but not for the reason you stated. As Evert already mentioned, an end user has access only to their own browser storage. **However**, it's still quite risky to store access tokens in the browser [because of XSS attacks](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps#name-cross-site-scripting-attack). here are some facts

1. Oauth 2.0 Access tokens are ***[bearer tokens](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6750)***, which simply means, there is no binding between the token itself, and who it was meant for. that is, anyone who ***has*** the token can use it.
2. When you store access tokens either in the session storage or local storage, you need to retrieve the tokens for later use in an API call
3. Client-side storage is ***generally*** vulnerable to cross-site scripting. in this case, any ***bad*** javascript code that manages to run in the same browsing context as your ***good*** Javascript code also can have access to the stored access token. this could be for instance injected code via a malicious browser extension or a vulnerable npm module you are using as an upstream dependency in your code.

Based on these facts, storing tokens on the client side can lead to token exfiltration. You can try to ***limit*** the potential of XSS by writing a proper content security policy (CSP) but the risk is still there. So if your application ***must*** store the tokens on the client side, you should either:

1. Store the tokens in the session storage (not local storage) to limit the exposure to only the current tab or session
2. Store the tokens in a service worker, this is much safer as workers run in a separate thread with isolated storage. but this is much more tricky in terms of state management because there is no guarantee that service workers will run persistently.

That being said, The OAuth Working Group suggests storing tokens server-side, assuming the Single Page Application (SPA) has a corresponding backend. Here's how this might work:

1. Users click "Login with Google" (Google is assumed for simplicity but it can be any other IDP) and are redirected to the backend endpoint `/api/oauth/google`. The backend initiates the OAuth or OIDC flow as a confidential client, retrieving the ID and access tokens.
2. These tokens are validated, stored server-side (in-memory, relational database, or key-value stores like Redis), and linked to the client through a session ID returned to the frontend.
3. Users are redirected back to the frontend with a session ID cookie

This is the [Backend For Frontend (BFF) pattern](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps#name-backend-for-frontend-bff-pr). acting as a proxy between the frontend and the backend, or being the backend itself. In this scenario, the frontend avoids handling authentication/authorization, sending requests to the backend which also auto-sends the session cookie. The backend handles the rest.

Addressing your second question, while the frontend can technically obtain the authorization server's (AS) public key to validate tokens, it's usually not necessary. OAuth tokens are meant to be "opaque" to the client - the client only needs to attach the token as an Authorization header, without understanding its content. Token validation and authorization decisions are the resource server's duty. If your frontend requires user profile data, you can use the access token to call the AS's `/userinfo` endpoint or create a custom `/userinfo` or `/me` endpoint in the resource server.

Comment: This is a great answer! I agree with everything you've written above.

Answer (score 1):

> Q1. isn't it unsafe to store the access token in javascript frontend? Because developer tools of the browser can unveil this access token which could be used by malicious users. Am I making sense here? If so, what is the proper way to host this access token in frontend once it gets it after authentication?

A user can only get access to their own token, not other people's tokens. There should be no circumstance where a user having access to their own token is a security risk.

> Q2. If frontend also wants to validate the token by checking the claims inside, it would mean the public key is needed in frontend, is that a fine way to go? If not, what would be the better way if frontend needs to validate the stored token when forming the subsequent requests to backend?

Yes there's nothing wrong with public keys being used anywhere. They are public.

You might also be interested in this document:

https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps-14.html

This will at one point be an RFC, and has _many) recommendations regarding browser-based apps.

Comment: Just to extend the answer, tokens are usually stored in `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`. They are exclusive for each web origin (protocol, hostname, port). So they can probably be compromised only by compromising the server or a DNS. And it's hard to fight this type of threats in a browser.
There are probably also attackers asking clueless users to do something in a browser Developer tools console, since Facebook displays a huge warning when you open it, but that's a kind of social engineering attack which is not based on a storage weakness.

Answer (score 0):

Tokens are also meant to be valid for a short time, so that also helps mitigate against the risk.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I don't use OAuth but I use JWT, the only things the token most do in frontend is to show user basic information, information that isn't relevant for things like authorization. I don't recommend validating token in the frontend because the sign you use to create the token most be in the front and that is a big security problem.
So answering your questions from my experience:

1. No, if you don't use information like password,credentials,etc to create the token.
2. You can validate token from frontend but you shouldn't, use middleware in the backend so you can validate token, you can decode token search for the user and bring the information if you don't want to use role or user type in the token, then you decide what operation do with it, if you let it pass to the route or don't, this is an example but with a simple middleware you can validate token in different ways

I hope I been clear, let me know if you have any other questions or to clarify something.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. First of all, I think you are most likely talking about ID token (from OpenID Connect) which is for user information, but I am actually asking around access token. Just to be clear, when you answer "No" for my 1st question, do you mean I shouldn't store the access token in frontend? If so, then how can subsequent requests from frontend having the access token in its request header? I mean how can frontend retrieve the token and put in request header, bear in mind that frontend got this token as a response when authenticate the user (login user).

Comment: When you authenticate a user first you send  a request to the backend and it return an ID token, so you can use it in several parts of your front end, you can store it on cookies is commonly used that way, but be careful about your information on that token,  then you have to put that token on your requests for the backend, this is a way to use this token. In Angular or React you add this token in a Interceptor, and add in a module, this way every request you make will have your bearer token in the header

Comment: Thank you Fermin, I understand your point. I would use exactly the same way to handle ID token as you described. But my question is around Access Token, I hope you don't mix ID token with Access Token.   ID token is for user information, but access token is for authorizing client to access backend resouces (e.g. APIs). So, unfortunately your answer is not exactly for my question even though you are right about ID token.  Basically, if I store Access Token in cookie it would be leaked since it is on browser, that would violate the purpose of access token.